# Wordpress Post Tags as Text

Tags: wordpress, tags

How to display wordpress post tags as text not as link? I have tried with the_tags(); function, and i got output as link. I am new wordpress. can any one give me solution?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to loop through the tags and retrieve their name"

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
  }
}
```

[the code is from the [wordpress dokumentation on get_the_tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags#Usage) (you could also use the_tags to retrieve the tags and loop through those as seen [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags#Example))]